# How to Configure Blackbox-exporter with Google Managed Prometheus?

Tags: prometheus, uptime, prometheus-blackbox-exporter, probe, google-managed-prometheus

I am migrating to Google Managed Prometheus. I've been using a helm deployed version of Prometheus to monitor my kubernetes cluster. The helm deployed Prometheus has a variety of selectors, including Pod Monitors, Service Monitors, and Probe Monitors. The Google Managed Prometheus only has pod monitors (PodMonitoring). I'm using Google Managed Prometheus with a managed collection.

I'd like to keep using my blackbox-exporter probes for uptime metrics. I configured this with a "kind: Probe" on my existing Prometheus. However, with Google Managed Promtheus only using PodMonitoring, I'm not sure that the blackbox-exporter is compatible.

I like the blackbox-exporter because I can configure it to check all my ingress hosts without having to manually create one for each. I'm frequently adding new ingresses with new endpoints to my cluster so this automation has been great.

Has anyone configured the blackbox-exporter with Google Managed Prometheus?

I've tried port forwarding the actual blackbox-exporter pod to see what metrics it exposes, but that doesn't show all the metrics I'd like.

Comment: Top-of-my-head because I've not tried deploying Blackbox Exporter with Google-managed Prometheus but, it should work. You'll have to deploy the Blackbox Exporter but you should then be able to create a `PodMonitor` to scrape its Pods. `PodMonitors` define a Prometheus target and give you the option to relabel but the metrics should be scraped as any other deployment. If you still need help, I'll try this tomorrow when I deploy a cluster next.

Comment: Is the issue because Blackbox Exporter uses [multi-target](https://github.com/prometheus/blackbox_exporter#prometheus-configuration)? Hmmm

Comment: Hypothesis: represent each Ingress as an item in `PodMonitor` `spec.endpoints` and define (metrics) `path` using [`probe` querystrings](https://github.com/prometheus/blackbox_exporter#checking-the-results)

Comment: Hmmm... I've been unsuccessful but I'll document (by way of an answer) what I've tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There can only (!?) be one `endpoints` item per `PodMonitoring` and the query string for `/probe?...` must be defined in terms of `params`. See examples below.

This restriction appears to contradict the CRDs:

- Google's variant [`PodMonitoring`](https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/docs/managed-prometheus/manifests#expandable-4)
- Prometheus Operator [`PodMonitor`](https://prometheus-operator.dev/docs/operator/api/#monitoring.coreos.com/v1.PodMonitor)

To probe multiple e.g. Ingresses, you could have a single Blackbox exporter `Deployment` **but** you'd need to have one `PodMonitoring` per Ingress, e.g.:

`podmonitorings.yaml`:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: List
metadata: {}
items:
- kind: PodMonitoring
  apiVersion: monitoring.googleapis.com/v1
  metadata:
    name: google-com
  spec:
    selector:
      matchLabels:
        app: blackbox
        type: exporter
    endpoints:
    - interval: 30s
      path: /probe
      params:
        target:
        - google.com
        module:
        - http_2xx
      port: 9115
    targetLabels:
      metadata:
      - pod
      - container
- kind: PodMonitoring
  apiVersion: monitoring.googleapis.com/v1
  metadata:
    name: stackoverflow-com
  spec:
    selector:
      matchLabels:
        app: blackbox
        type: exporter
    endpoints:
    - interval: 30s
      path: /probe
      params:
        target:
        - stackoverflow.com
        module:
        - http_2xx
      port: 9115
    targetLabels:
      metadata:
      - pod
      - container
- kind: PodMonitoring
  apiVersion: monitoring.googleapis.com/v1
  metadata:
    name: prometheus-com
  spec:
    selector:
      matchLabels:
        app: blackbox
        type: exporter
    endpoints:
    - interval: 30s
      path: /probe
      params:
        target:
        - prometheus.io
        module:
        - http_2xx
      port: 9115
    targetLabels:
      metadata:
      - pod
      - container
```

`blackbox-exporter.yaml` config defines:

1. `ConfigMap` that defines a Blackbox Exporter config

   - (using the documented) `http_2xx`
   - and I added a `foo` (gRPC prober)
2. `Deployment` of the Blackbox Exporter using the `ConfigMap`

`blackbox-exporter.yaml`:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: List
metadata: {}
items:
- kind: ConfigMap
  apiVersion: v1
  metadata:
    name: blackbox-exporter
  data:
    blackbox.yml: |+
      modules:
        http_2xx:
          prober: http
          timeout: 5s
          http:
            valid_http_versions: ["HTTP/1.1", "HTTP/2.0"]
            valid_status_codes: []  # Defaults to 2xx
            method: GET
            follow_redirects: true
            fail_if_ssl: false
            fail_if_not_ssl: false
            tls_config:
              insecure_skip_verify: false
            preferred_ip_protocol: "ip4" # defaults to "ip6"
            ip_protocol_fallback: false  # no fallback to "ip6"
        foo:
          prober: grpc
          grpc:
            service: ""
            preferred_ip_protocol: ip4
            tls: true
            tls_config:
              insecure_skip_verify: false
- kind: Deployment
  apiVersion: apps/v1
  metadata:
      name: blackbox-exporter
  spec:
    selector:
      matchLabels:
        app: blackbox
        type: exporter
    template:
      metadata:
        labels:
          app: blackbox
          type: exporter
      spec:
        containers:
        - name: blackbox-exporter
          image: docker.io/prom/blackbox-exporter:v0.24.0
          args:
          - --config.file=/config/blackbox.yml
          ports:
          - name: http
            containerPort: 9115
          volumeMounts:
          - name: vol
            mountPath: /config
        volumes:
        - name: vol
          configMap:
            name: blackbox-exporter
```

```bash
NAMESPACE="test"

kubectl create namespace ${NAMESPACE}

# Deploy Blackbox exporter
kubectl apply \
--filename=${PWD}/blackbox-exporter.yaml \
--namespace=${NAMESPACE}

# Apply PodMonitorings
kubectl apply \
--filename=${PWD}/podmonitorings.yaml \
--namespace=${NAMESPACE}
```

Then you'll need to `PATCH` `operatorconfig/config` in Namespace `gmp-public`. There are several ways to do this. Don't delete any content from this file but ensure that `matchOneOf` list includes some of the newly expected metric names:

```bash
KUBE_EDITOR=nano kubectl edit operatorconfig/config \
--namespace=gmp-public
```

You'll want to add the metrics that you want to include:

```
apiVersion: monitoring.googleapis.com/v1
collection:
  filter:
    matchOneOf:
    - '{__name__=~"blackbox_exporter_.+"}'
    - '{__name__=~"probe_.+"}'
  kubeletScraping:
    interval: 30s
kind: OperatorConfig
metadata:
  name: config
```

Once scraped (~1m), you will see `blackbox_exporter_*` and `probe_*` metrics listed under Metrics Diagnostics:

[image]

And be able to query them in Google's Metrics exporter and the Google-managed Prometheus frontend:

[image]

`https://console.cloud.google.com/monitoring/metrics-diagnostics;duration=PT1H?project={project}`

You can port-forward to the Blackbox Exporter to execute probes:

```bash
kubectl port-forward deployment/blackbox-exporter \
--namespace=${NAMESPACE} \
9115:9115
```

And then (locally):

```bash
# Blackbox Exporter's metrics
curl --get http://localhost:9115/metrics

# Blackbox Exporter's HTTP probe for e.g. Google
curl --get http://localhost:9115/probe?target=google.com&module=http_2xx

# Blackbox Exporter's gRPC probe for Google's Cloud Profiler
curl --get http://localhost:9115/probe?target=cloudprofiler.googleapis.com:443&module=foo
```

Comment: Thank you! A follow up question:

If I don't do a "matchOneOf" then won't it collect all the blackbox_exporter and probe (and every other kubelet metric) by default?

Comment: That's correct. You must explicitly include the metrics that you want it to scrape.